# how to properly reflect changes from branch to another with rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have three branches named `master`, `foo` and `bar`. `foo` and `bar` both branches are created with `master` branch. When I make changes in `foo`(a very minor on which is very important for `bar` too) I want the same changes to be applied to `bar` and vice versa.

I think, I can do merge and rebase but merging is long way to go. I don't want `master` to be affected, just `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Cherry pick your foo commit in bar  edit : See Ivan answer

Answer (score 2):

You can `git cherry-pick` your commit from `foo` to `bar`. 
Just find out what the `SHA` of the commit is, navigate to `bar` and run `git cherry-pick <SHA_ID>`.

You can find more on `cherry-pick` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution would be to rebase `bar` on top of `foo`, and to redo the rebase whenever `foo` changes.

This would be simpler than having to cherry pick your changes.  For one thing, it would be much easier to see whether you'd missed anything in `foo`; you'd know because `foo` would diverge.  With `git cherry-pick` you wouldn't get that kind of visual confirmation.